# Anchor in React

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, navigation, anchor

I am trying to make something like this in my React frontend:

```html
<p>
 <h1>Foo</h1>
 <a href="#second"></a>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

 <h2>Bar</h2>
 <a name="second"></a>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
</p>
```

But when I try to create the anchor tag, it tells me that `Property 'name' does not exist on type <HTMLAnchorElement>`

How can I make such navigation within an article in React?

Answer (score 1):

This is TypeScript helping you out - the `name` field is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#name), use `id` instead.